# Slit size vs. object size in double slit experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, wavefunction, interference, double-slit-experiment

In classical optics, the double slit experiment show interference of light. The spacing of the fringes at a distance $z$ from the slits is [given by](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Classical_wave-optics_formulation)
$$
w \approx \dfrac{z \lambda}{d} \;,
$$
where $d$ is the slit distance, and $\lambda$ the light wavelength. Moreover, I think  one has to remember that for this interference to happen the width of the slits needs to be of order (or smaller than) $\lambda$. The Wiki page cited above sys " If the width of the slits is small enough (much less than the wavelength of the laser light), the slits diffract the light into cylindrical waves." which is needed for interference to occur.

In quantum mechanics, according to wave-particle duality, a particle of mass $m$ moving at speed $v$ is associated to a de Broglie wavelength of
$$
\lambda_{\text{dB}} = \dfrac{h}{m v} \;,
$$
where $h$ is the Planck constant, and therefore can also interfere in a double slit experiment.

Questions I have:

1. Considering what we have said so far, I'm not sure I understand how it was possible to observe interference of fullerene with $\lambda_{\text{dB}}=2.5\,$pm using a grating with 50 nm slits with 100 nm period [(see the paper)](http://davidlu.net/c60article.pdf). There are four order of magnitude difference between wavelength and width, so they are not really comparable.
2. What is the longitudinal/transversal coherence, and how does it play a role?
3. Fullerene has a diameter of 1 nm, so it can pass through relatively small slits. But  its size is already three orders of magnitude larger than $\lambda_{\text{dB}}$. For compounds of even larger masses, this ratio between size and wavelength is going to be even smaller. Therefore, what is the limit in scaling up such an experiment, if one considers that at some point the object will not be able to pass anymore through the slits (that need to be comparable to $\lambda_{\text{dB}}$).